# openni_kinect: [openni_node1-2] process has died

Tags: kinect, openni-kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm using Ubuntu 10.04.3 and the *ros-electric-openni-kinect* package. When I try

```
roslaunch openni_camera openni_node.launch
```

I receive

```
[ INFO] [1320414269.335861019]: [/openni_node1] Number devices connected: 1
[ INFO] [1320414269.337386912]: [/openni_node1] 1. device on bus 001:08 is a Xbox NUI Camera (2ae) from Microsoft (45e) with serial id 'A003619160******'
[ INFO] [1320414269.343809795]: [/openni_node1] searching for device with index = 1
[openni_node1-2] process has died [pid 1734, exit code -4].
```

By searching the web, I found out that the reason for this is probably that my CPU does not support SSE3 instructions. As the only solution (apart from buying a new CPU) seems to be a manual source-based installation of the openni_kinect stack, I tried to follow the advice given [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/341/how-to-compile-openni_ros-with-sse2-only-support), but the CMakeLists.txt does not contain the line which is mentioned there.

Can anybody confirm that the pre-compiled package (installed by *sudo apt-get install ros-electric-openni-kinect*) requires SSE3 support? And, if so, what would be the easiest way to obtain a build that only makes use of SSE2 instructions?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11797/openni_kinect:-%5Bopenni_node1-2%5D-process-has-died/) by [ph4nt0m](https://answers.ros.org/users/1315/ph4nt0m/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2011-11-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try building it from source yourself and turning off the SSE3 in the configuration step.

---

Originally posted by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) with karma: 2962 on 2011-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ph4nt0m](https://answers.ros.org/users/1315/ph4nt0m/) on 2011-11-05**:
Thank you for your answer! I didn't really know what you mean by "configuration step", so I simply tried to compile it without any modification and it works :) I guess the "rosbuild_check_for_sse ()" in "CMakeLists.txt" switched off SSE3 automatically so there was no need to change any flag by hand.